# Redirecting users from one page to the other

Tags: asp.net

I have a page which gets all its data from the database

www.mysite.com/List/Oct/DisplayPost.aspx?id=120

Now I want to redirect this page to

www.mysite.com/List/Oct/DisplayPost.aspx?id=150

Is that possible. What are the different ways to do it? Any easy way out?

[Update]: It's a Master/Content page scenario. More there is only one page called DisplayPost.aspx (like a template page)..the DisplayPost.aspx?id=x gets generated dynamically taking data from the database.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer (aside from a client redirect using Javascript).
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840052/server-transfer-and-system-threading-threadabortexception) for a discussion of Server.Transfer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Redirect("~/DisplayPost.aspx?id=150")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ASP Redirect Method](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/met_redirect.asp) and please always take a look at W3 first. ;)
Do like this:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "www.mysite.com/List/Oct/DisplayPost.aspx?id=150"
%>
```

Comment: `ASP != ASP.NET && w3schools.com != msdn.microsoft.com`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a permanent redirect, have you considered a [permanent 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440883/mass-301-redirects-in-asp-net-including-pages-that-need-to-redirect-to-a-differe) for that specific URL?

EDIT:  When I say specific URL I mean, ww.mysite.com/List/Oct/DisplayPost.aspx?id=120.

Comment: Rick..I have no idea of the IIS my hosting is using..they do not respond back..is there any other technique..www.mysite.com/List/Oct/DisplayPost.aspx?id=120 is a Content page by the way

Comment: You'll probably have to look for 120 in your query-string variable on Page_Load and replace it with 150.