# how to load aspx files programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to web development. I have 2 .aspx files and in default page I want to open other page programmatically. how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to redirect the user to another page?

Comment: What do you mean by *open*? You want to fetch the html generated by this ASPX page in your code behind?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve more clearly to get a definitive response.

Comment: While it was not obvious at first, OP's comment to ChrisF's answer confirms that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596282/redirecting-users-from-one-page-to-the-other (and possibly many others)

Comment: @Jørn - I should have realised it would be a duplicate and searched myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx) method:

> The following example shows you how to use the VBScript programming language to redirect the user to a virtual directory on the same IIS server.

```
<% Response.Redirect "/samples/asp/newpage.asp" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two you can use Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer.  Response.Redirect forces the browser to load a new page a new URL, while Server.Transfer changes the paged being loaded on the server.

Here is an article on the two:

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=15

MSDN Response.Redirect:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect.aspx

MSDN Server.Transfer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are looking for but at a guess you should be using user control (.ascx) and rendering them on the page.